# ggplot lab expressions with left and right parentheses

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a y-label an `expression`. In Latex the expression I am looking for is

```
\left(\frac{top}{bottom}\right)\times 100
```

which looks like the following

[image]

How do I make a label like this in ggplot2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ggplot() + ylab(~ italic(bgroup("(", over( top, bottom), ")") ~ '\u00D7' ~  100))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @g-g-grothendieck, any suggestions on where to look in the ggplot2 library to explore creating expressions such as these?

Comment: It's in grDevices in the base of R, not ggplot2.  Try `?plotmath` and `demo(plotmath)`

Comment: @g-grothendieck, thank you for the response. It is helpful.